no deja guarda los usuarios apenas registro otro ya desaparece el otro o ninguna registra, ¿como puedo hacer para que guarde los usuarios?

Como hago en javascript para que la base de datos deje guardados los usuarios sin importar cuantas veces se agreguen diferentes usuarios? y como hago para que un usuario no se pueda registrar mas de dos veces un código ?

El código debe ir como texto y formateado como código usando las herramientas del sitio.

No puedo salvar nada de esto, habría que explicar desde las bases de programación acá.

Para no registrar dos veces un usuario, verifica que el usuario exista primero. Si ya existe, mensaje de error. Si no existe, lo crea.

Bienvenida a SO!
Respondiendo a tu pregunta: El problema puntual es que al registrar un usuario en la función agregarUsuario lo guardas en la variable incorrecta:
ingreso[nombreIngresado] = contraseñaIngresado
Debería ser:
persona[nombreIngresado] = contrasenaIngresado
Consejo Adicional:
Si estás practicando/aprendiendo Javascript, esta bien que uses alert y prompt, pero en un caso real lo correcto es crear una interface HTML con cajas de texto (<input type="text" />) y botones (<button type="button">Agregar...</button>) para que el usuario interactue con tu aplicación. También recomiendo que las variables donde guardas el nombre y contraseña, la definas localmente en cada función que las requiera, en lugar de globalmente (al principio de tu código). Y cuando hagas pregutas en SO, es preferible que pegues el código en lugar de una foto, ya que hace más fácil para nosotros probarlo y ayudarte.
